# service stack using OrmLiteOrmLite and t4 to create poco

Tags: servicestack, t4, ormlite-servicestack

so usgin the given t4 files https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/src/T4

i can't make it work, i get this error: i see that is a problem that it call the 32bit version but i use the 64bit version I search and try the posible solution and no work for me the posible solution was (PlatformTarget AnyCPU) but still not work. any ideas?

> Error 1 Assembly Load Problem The following exception occurred :'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll' Se produjo la siguiente excepción:
>   System.BadImageFormatException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.
>   Nombre de archivo: 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
>      en System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      en System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      en System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      en System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      en System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
>      en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.AttemptAssemblyLoad(String assemblyName)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is disabled .
>   To enable logging assembly bind failure , set the registry value [ HKLM \ Software \ Microsoft \ Fusion! EnableLog ] (DWORD ) to 1.
>   Note : There is some performance penalty associated error log Assembly binding .
>   To turn this feature off , remove the registry value [ HKLM \ Software \ Microsoft \ Fusion! EnableLog ] .

using vs2012 in a windows 8

Comment: OrmLite T4 templates work fine for me on VS2012 / Windows 8.  Could you put some more information about your setup - what is your connection string?

Comment: <!--<add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=vfsb;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx;" providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" />-->

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

Here are my steps to make it work:

- Create a new console app in Visual Studio 2013
- Add your "ConnectionString in your App.config
- In Nuget Console:Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer
- In Nuget Console:Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.T4  (ignore the errors)
- remove the blank line on the top and bottom of the file for all the .tt files
  OrmLite.Core.ttinclude    OrmLite.Poco.tt     OrmLite.SP.tt
- Compile your project.

> Blockquote